# While statement in paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, paintcomponent

I am trying to make a simple tile system for my game. I made a test tile and I am trying to paint 5 tiles next to each other. I made a while statement in my `paintComponent` where it counts down from 5 and each time it draws one tile and adds 10 (size of the tile) to the current x value. But for some reason none of the tiles shows up. If I comment out the while statement one tile shows up. So the image is being loaded. For some reason the while statement messes the painting up. Would really appreciate some help.

Here is my code from my paintComponents

- the variable numOfTiles = 5
- the variable tileStartx = 100;
- the variable chosenTile is my image.

---

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(tileToDraw != null){
        while(numOfTiles > 0){
            System.out.println(tileStartx);
            g.drawImage (chosenTile, tileStartx, tileStarty, this);
            tileStartx += 10;
            numOfTiles--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if all you want is painting tiles based on an image, you can use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
while(numOfTiles > 0){
```

to

```
// or the more modern variant shown by Kumar
for (int count=0; count<numOfTiles; count++) {
```

and remove:

```
    numOfTiles--;
```

Explanation.  I suspect `numOfTiles` is being reduced to 0 in the first paint and never gets reset.  The `for` loop takes care of that by never changing the value.

Also note Walter's tweak:

```
    g.drawImage (chosenTile, tileStartx + (count * 10), tileStarty, this);
```

instead of:

```
    g.drawImage (chosenTile, tileStartx, tileStarty, this);
    tileStartx += 10;
```

Comment: I would also change the draw image to:
g.drawImage (chosenTile, tileStartx + (count * 10), tileStarty, this);
and remove the tileStartx += 10 or the tiles will shift right on each repaint

Comment: @WalterLaan Good point.  Apparently I failed to take in the subtlety of that 'weighty volume' of code snippet.  I never look at snippets very closely. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
for (int i : numOfTiles){

            System.out.println(tileStartx);
            g.drawImage (chosenTile, tileStartx, tileStarty, this);
            tileStartx += 10;

        }
```

Comment: *"Thank you.."* Why thank me?  You're the one that put in the hard work, wrote answers obviously worth at least 100 up-votes.  BTW - thanks for reminding me of that shortcut for array counters.  I must use it more often.

Comment: Its an honor to receive a thanks for a person like you, who has such great knowledge, this comment will be like an asset to me.